# Invite new user to edit record in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, email-validation

I want to invite a new user (that not used the website before) to edit an existing Firebase record. (edit record of a location where I know the email address of the owner).

What is a possible approach?

Saving records should be generally protected by rules: email is verfified(!) and userId corresponds to a field in the record.

I could manually set up the user with password and random password first and save the userid in the record. But I do not see a way to set the email as verified (to allow later saving)? Even if I could, how do I sent a link to a user so he can sign in with his user credential.

There might be another way that I do not see. I would appreciate some direction. Thanks!